# October CMS include class

Tags: php, octobercms

I want to use FPDF class in my october plugin for create PDF from some record data. 
In my plugin directory i create classes folder and here i create fpdf.php class and set namespace

```html
namespace Author\Pluginname\Classes;
```

In my controller i use

```html
use Author\Pluginname\Classes\TCPDF;
```

and create public function createPdf($id) where i set

```html
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

But i get error Class 'Author\Pluginname\Classes\TCPDF' not found

Full controller

```html
<?php namespace Author\Pluginname\Controllers;

use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use BackendMenu;
use Author\Pluginname\Classes\TCPDF;

class Reservations extends Controller
{
    public $implement = ['Backend\Behaviors\ListController', 'Backend\Behaviors\FormController'];

    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function createPdf($id)
    {
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: is `fpdf.php` class `TCPDF`  if so these should be identical, and well they are not.  Which is standard auto loading practice.  In other words if you have `class TCPDF` in a file named `fpdf.php` you will never be able to auto load it using PSR0/4 as the class name and file name should match (case included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is file name issue.

> **Directory structure** and **File Name** should look like this.

[image]

> Your `FPDF.php` file code should look like this.

[image]

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SoTest\Classes;

class FPDF {

    public static function hello() {
      echo "<pre/>";print_r('its ok');exit();
      // .. other code
    }

    // .. other code

}
```

> You can **use** it like this

[image]

```
use HardikSatasiya\SoTest\Classes\FPDF;

function onStart() {

    $fpdf = new FPDF();
    // .. other code
}
```

Then it should work properly.

If any doubt please comment.